# If number of files in a folder exceeds 10000 create new subfolder in r

Tags: r

I have been working with `moveud` (https://github.com/bacollier/moveud) for a while and might have found a reason to why the code runs slow at some point.

By accident i deleted the folder and "put it back" after renaming it and the code sped up again. Where the code would run for at least a day and produce errors at random (due to file write errors???), it now runs in less than an hour!

So my question is:

Is there anyway to include a counter in the code that would produce a new subfolder with e.g. _1, _2 and so on for each 10000 files in a folder?

This is my code:

UD_subs5_ving13_split is a product from the `move` package and contains approx 27000 rows and the file product will be approx 4 times that number.

In my case i would want to have 5 folders UDsubs5ving13_1 to UDsubs5ving13_5.

Is that possible to incorporate that in the code below to the `path=` part of the code below by e.g using `paste`?

should one use something like `length(list.files("/path_to_files")`?

```
mclapply(UD_subs5_ving13_split, function(x){
  for(j in 4:nrow(x@DBMvar)){
    tryCatch({
      move.forud(x,
                 range.subset=j:nrow(x@DBMvar),
                 ts=1,
                 ras=20,lev=c(0.2,.5,.95),
                 le=20,
                 crs='+proj=longlat +zone=32 +datum=WGS84',
                 name=paste(names(x), "", sep = "_"),
                 ID=names(x),
                 **path="UDsubs5ving13"**)
    }, warning = function(w) {
      warning = paste(x@DBMvar@idData$trackId, "", sep = "_")
    }, error=function(e) {
      j = j + 2
    })
  }
}, mc.cores = 6)
```

Comment: This is fairly easy. Use git to checkout the repo (if you haven't done so already) and edit [`move.forud.R`](https://github.com/bacollier/moveud/blob/master/R/move.forud.R#L65) in line 65 to make a check.

Comment: super will look into that

Comment: I see what you mean, but how would it be done?

Comment: Just a second, had to go out of the office for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic I used in this answer is to learn how many subsets you have. Calculate approximately how many folder will be needed to fill 1000 files into each. For each subset, precalculate this folder and paste it together just in time for writing. This solution assumes folders are being created by `writeOGR`.

```
move.forud=function(x, range.subset, ts, ras, le, lev, crs, path, name, ID) {
  object<-x@DBMvar
  if(length(range.subset)<2)
    stop("\nrange.subset must have length >1\n")
  if(length(le)==1) location.error=rep(c(le), nrow(object))
  if(length(le)>1)  location.error=c(le)

  # calculate number of subfolders needed to house 1000 files each
  num.subfolders <- ceiling(length(range.subset)/1000) 
  # create in advance to which subfolder shapefiles will be written to
  subfolder <- sprintf("/_%d", rep(1:num.subfolders, each = 1000))

  for(i in range.subset) {
    object@interest<-rep(F, nrow(object)); object@interest[i]<-T;times=object@timestamps[i];var=object@means[i];
    x.out <- brownian.bridge.dyn(object,raster=ras, time.step=ts, location.error=location.error)
    xx=raster2contour(x.out, level=lev)
    xx=spTransform(xx, CRS=CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'))
    xx=SpatialLines2PolySet(xx)
    xx=PolySet2SpatialPolygons(xx)
    xx=as(xx, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
    xx$levels=lev
    xx$times=times
    xx$stepvar=var
    xx$ID=ID

    writeOGR(xx, dsn=paste(path, subfolder[i], sep = ""), layer=paste(name, i, sep=""), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
  }
}
```

Comment: writeOGR is used indeed and the subset could be set to 10.000. I will try to check out the code at do the suggested alterations :D

Comment: @NicolaiJørgensen I misread 10000 for 1000, but yes, just modify lines with `num.subfolders` and `subfolder` accordingly. If you are using git, you can changes to an offshoot branch first and once you get it to work, you can merge it back into the main branch. Alternatively, you can suggest a pull request to the original author if he is willing to incorporate your changes into the main package branch.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try out the code and if it works a s desired i will suggest it to him. With reference to this thread :)

Comment: a little typo in the last line : Double comma .

Comment: @NicolaiJørgensen thanks. Next time feel free to edit my answer any way you wish.